# Use one array to filter out another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to use one array filter out another array with non-zero value?

```
from numpy import array

a = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

b = array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 5, 0, 0]])
```

Expected result:

```
array([[ 0, 0, 2,  0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 7,  0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 12, 0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 17, 0, 0],
       [ 0, 0, 22, 0, 0]])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if you want a new array would be `np.where` with 3 arguments:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.where(b, a, 0)
array([[ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  7,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 17,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 22,  0,  0]])
```

If you want to change `a` in-place you could instead use boolean indexing based on `b`:

```
>>> a[b == 0] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  7,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 17,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 22,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

`a * (b != 0)`